# SQL y .setFloat error de Syntaxis (Java)

Tags: java, sql

hola estoy aprendiendo a hacer un CRUD con servlets de java y jsp usando el MVC. Tengo una tabla donde figuran todos los elementos de una tabla de base de datos. Por cada uno de ellos, hay un link que dice ACTUALIZAR. La idea es que al apretar ese botón, el JSP donde está dicho link envíe el precio del articulo seleccionado (que es un campo primario) al Controlador y este lo envíe al Modelo quien finalmente usa un PreparedStatement con una sentencia SELECT * WHERE (precio)... donde debería ubicar en la BDD al único artículo al que le corresponde ese precio.  Sin embargo me arroja el siguiente error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (2.0)' /   2.0 hace referencia al precio que elegí actualizar. Y se ejecuta el bloque dentro del Catch.   No entiendo donde está el error la verdad pasé mas de 2 horas intentando arreglarlo.

Método del Modelo que da error:  (importante: este método recibe un float. Aquí no está el error. El float que recibe del método del controlador es correcto. Además, el campo precio de la BDD EFECTIVAMENTE es un float).

```
    public Articulos actualizar(float precio) {
        
     Connection miconexion;
     PreparedStatement mistatement ;
     ResultSet miresultset;
     String descripcion = null;
     int codigo = 0;
     try {
            miconexion = pool.getConnection(); //pool es una variable DataSource 
            
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE (precio) VALUES (?)";
            mistatement = miconexion.prepareStatement(sql);
            mistatement.setFloat(1, precio);
            miresultset = mistatement.executeQuery();
            
            if(miresultset.next()) {
                
                 codigo = miresultset.getInt("codigo");
                 descripcion = miresultset.getString("descripcion");
            }
            
            Articulos objetoactualizable = new Articulos(descripcion, codigo);
            return objetoactualizable;
        
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        
            System.out.println("algo falló");
        
            Articulos falla = new Articulos("lala",344);
            return falla;
        }
```

Método que recibe el precio y vincula con BDD de la clase Modelo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu consulta SQL es incorrecta, VALUES solo tiene sentido en los inserts. El error te dice que tienes un error de sitaxis en el SQL, no en el código Java:

```
SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE precio = ?
```